# "Smart" sudoku brute-forcer

Tags: java, performance, recursion, sudoku

After running my C-brute-forcer for two days on a 25x25 sudoku, I decided to re-write in Java so that it would solve it in an acceptable time frame. The idea: Make smart fields that contain all possible values for that field, and then let the bute-forcer only loop through these, hopefully reducing the time.

After some head-scratching, I came up with this:

Main:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class SudokuMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] dims = null;
        String fields = null;

        File file = new File("./io/sudoku6");

        try (BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

            dims = buf.readLine().split(" ");
            fields = buf.readLine();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        if (dims.length != 3) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid info header!");
        }

        int w = Integer.parseInt(dims[0]);
        int h = Integer.parseInt(dims[1]);
        int size = Integer.parseInt(dims[2]);

        if (fields.length() != size * size * 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    String.format("Invalid sudoku! Expected length %s, got %s.\n", size * size * 2, fields.length()));
        }

        Sudoku sudoku = new Sudoku(w, h, size, fields);

        SudokuSolver.solve(sudoku);

    }
}
```

Sudoku:

```
public class Sudoku {

    private Field fields[];

    public int fWidth, fHeight, size;

    public Sudoku(int w, int h, int size, String raw) {
        this.fWidth = w;
        this.fHeight = h;
        this.size = size;
        fields = new Field[size * size];

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < size * size; i++) {
                int num = Integer.parseInt(raw.substring(0, 2));
                fields[i] = new Field(num, size);
                raw = raw.substring(2);
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Sudoku contains non-number characters!");
        }

    }

    public Field getFieldAt(int x, int y) {
        return fields[y * size + x];
    }

    public int getValueAt(int x, int y) {
        return fields[y * size + x].value;
    }

    public void setValueAt(int x, int y, int val) {
        fields[y * size + x].value = val;
    }

    private int[] getRow(int row) {
        int[] res = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            res[i] = fields[i + row * size].value;
        }
        return res;
    }

    private int[] getCol(int col) {
        int[] res = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            res[i] = fields[col + i * size].value;
        }
        return res;
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        for (int y = 0; y < this.size; y++) {
            int[] values = new int[size + 1];
            for (int i : this.getRow(y)) {
                if (values[i] != 0) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    values[i] = i;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < this.size; x++) {
            int[] values = new int[size + 1];

            for (int i : this.getCol(x)) {
                if (values[i] != 0) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    values[i] = i;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int yf = 0; yf < this.size; yf+=fHeight) {
            for (int xf = 0; xf < this.size; xf+=fWidth) {
                int[] values = new int[size + 1];
                for (int i : this.getBox(xf, yf)) {
                    if (values[i] != 0) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        values[i] = i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private int[] getBox(int xf, int yf) {
        int[] res = new int[size];
        int i = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < fHeight; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < fWidth; x++) {
                res[i] = fields[(y + yf) * size + (x+xf)].value;
                i++;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public void print() {

        for (int a = 0; a < size * 3 + (size / fWidth) + 1; a++) {
            System.out.print('-');
        }
        System.out.println();

        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if (i % fWidth == 0) {
                    System.out.print('|');
                }
                System.out.printf("%3d", fields[j * size + i].value);
            }

            System.out.print('|');
            System.out.println();

            if (j % fHeight == fHeight - 1) {
                for (int a = 0; a < (size * 3) + (size / fWidth) + 1; a++) {
                    System.out.print('-');
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

Field:

```
public class Field {

    public int value;
    private int possible[];

    public Field(int val, int size) {
        this.value = val;
        possible = new int[size + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
            possible[i] = i;
        }
    }

    public void removePossible(int[] nums) {
        for (int num : nums)
            possible[num] = 0;
    }

    public int setIfOnePossible() {

        if (value != 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        int found = -1;
        for (int i = 1; i < possible.length; i++) {
            if (possible[i] != 0) {
                if (found == -1) {
                    found = i;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        this.value = found;
        return 1;
    }

    public boolean isPossible(int n) {
        return possible[n] != 0;
    }

    public int countPossible() {
        int res = 0;
        if (value != 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        for (int i : possible) {
            if (i != 0) {
                res++;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

}
```

SudokuSolver:

```
public class SudokuSolver {

    private static int tries;

    public static void solve(Sudoku s) {
        s.print();
        long then = System.currentTimeMillis();

        presolve(s);
        if (recsolve(s) && s.isValid()) {
            s.print();
            long mstime = System.currentTimeMillis() - then;

            int min = (int) (mstime / 1000 / 60 % 60);
            int sec = (int) (mstime / 1000 % 60);
            long ms = mstime - (min * 60 * 1000) - (sec * 1000);
            System.out.printf("Took %d min, %d s, %d ms\n", min, sec, ms);
            System.out.printf("%d tries.\n", tries);
        }
    }

    private static boolean recsolve(Sudoku s) {
        for (int y = 0; y < s.size; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < s.size; x++) {
                Field f = s.getFieldAt(x, y);
                if (f.value == 0) {
                    for (int n = 1; n <= s.size; n++) {
                        if (f.isPossible(n)) {
                            tries++;
                            s.setValueAt(x, y, n);
                            if (s.isValid() && recsolve(s)) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    s.setValueAt(x, y, 0);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static void presolve(Sudoku s) {
        int possBefore = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < s.size; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < s.size; x++) {
                possBefore += s.getFieldAt(x, y).countPossible();
            }
        }

        int set = 0;

        do {
            for (int y = 0; y < s.size; y++) {
                int[] found = new int[s.size + 1];
                for (int x = 0; x < s.size; x++) {
                    int value = s.getValueAt(x, y);
                    found[value] = value;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < s.size; i++) {
                    s.getFieldAt(i, y).removePossible(found);
                }
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < s.size; x++) {
                int[] found = new int[s.size + 1];
                for (int y = 0; y < s.size; y++) {
                    int value = s.getValueAt(x, y);
                    found[value] = value;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < s.size; i++) {
                    s.getFieldAt(x, i).removePossible(found);
                }
            }

            for (int yf = 0; yf < s.size; yf += s.fHeight) {
                for (int xf = 0; xf < s.size; xf += s.fWidth) {
                    int[] found = new int[s.size + 1];
                    for (int y = 0; y < s.fHeight; y++) {
                        for (int x = 0; x < s.fWidth; x++) {
                            int value = s.getValueAt(xf + x, yf + y);
                            found[value] = value;
                        }
                    }
                    for (int y = 0; y < s.fHeight; y++) {
                        for (int x = 0; x < s.fWidth; x++) {
                            s.getFieldAt(xf + x, yf + y).removePossible(found);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            set = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < s.size; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < s.size; x++) {
                    set += s.getFieldAt(x, y).setIfOnePossible();
                }
            }
        } while (set != 0);

        int possAfter = 0;

        for (int y = 0; y < s.size; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < s.size; x++) {
                possAfter += s.getFieldAt(x, y).countPossible();
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("Excluded %s possible values for fields. (before %s, now %s)\n", possBefore - possAfter,
                possBefore, possAfter);
    }

}
```

This happens to be >5 seconds faster than the C program on a 12x12 sudoku like this one:

```
4 3 12
000000000001000000000312030001000000121006000000000002120403000000000700001000081200000007000600000705000002000300000400000000090000000711030010050009110700000002000000000600000200010000051200001200020000000408001100000200000000070803110000000000030912000000040002100400000000030000000000
```

(I haven't tested the 25x25 yet.)

EDIT: 
Removed two test-cases

Answer (score 2):

Your `recsolve` method changes a value in the grid, then validates the entire puzzle, recursing if it's valid or aborting if that change broke the puzzle.  However, changing one number only impacts three things.  The column/row for the value that's been changed and the box that contains it.  A change to the top left box isn't going to impact if the bottom right box is valid, so there's not point testing it.  Providing an overload of the `isValid` method that takes in the coodinates of the changed cell can result in a significant speed improvement.

The recursive call in `recsolve` becomes:

```
if (s.isValid(x,y) && recsolve(s)) {
```

And `isValid` would look something like:

```
public boolean isValid(int changedX, int changedY) {
    int boxChangedX = changedX - changedX % fWidth;
    int boxChangedY = changedY - changedY % fHeight;

    return isValidSet(getRow(changedY))
            && isValidSet(getCol(changedX))
            && isValidSet(getBox(boxChangedX, boxChangedY));
}
```

Note, I've extracted a common function, which checks if the values returned from `getRow`, `getCol` or `getBox` contain a valid set of values..

```
private boolean isValidSet(int[] knownData) {
    int[] values = new int[size + 1];
    for (int i : knownData) {
        if (values[i] != 0) {
            return false;
        }
        values[i] = i;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Other thoughts**

- Give parameter variables descriptive names, they're often expanded by intellisense... `Sudoku(int w, int h, int size, String raw)`, `w` could be `width`.  Variable naming in general could be more expressive.
- We don't tend to prefix `this.` unless there's a name clash, so just `fWidth = w;` is fine...
- When an `if` always returns, you don't need to have an `else`.   So, rather than:

  > ```
  > if (values[i] != 0) {
  >     return false;
  > } else {
  >     values[i] = i;
  > }
  > ```

  Prefer:

  ```
  if (values[i] != 0) {
    return false;
  }
  values[i] = i;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This code looks largely OK to me. I've written a Sudoku resolver myself, mainly to test my coding skills on the then new Collection framework (which again, shows my age).

A few remarks then:

- The rows, columns and blocks can be seen as "groups". That way it would even be possible to allow Sudoku's with different or additional groups.
- I don't know the speed of my Sudoku for 12 x 12, but I do know that it ran in 0.2 seconds on my dual core core 2 based IBM cheapo thinkpad for 9 x 9. And that was basically the startup time of the VM.
- I used a two step guessing -> simple reduction of possible values for each "group", and then taking a guess. So if possible I would run `presolve` not only at the start, but also after each guess.  There are many tricks that can be used to be able to "guess" better, but most of them seem to slow down the guessing really (I played fair and looked up the tricks after getting it running).

As for the code:

- the parameters of the Sudoku `w`, `h`, `size` / `fields` all seem related. Only use those that are really required. Isn't `size = w * h`?
- The Field class is a bit weird. It has a special field for `value` and it is unclear if that is needed. It uses `0` as special value. For such a special value I would use a constant (e.g. `NOT_POSSIBLE = 0`) and document the use. Furthermore, it seems to rely on external calls to `setIfOnePossible` to get into the next valid state. I can remember I used `Set<Integer>` instead, with no significant issues (but then, my goal was to test the collection classes). `setIfOnePossible` returns a value, but that's not clear from the name.
- `public boolean isValid()` has side effects. A method that is called `isValid` should not contain any side effects, so it is really important that you rename the method.
- `raw = raw.substring(2)` generally we frown upon using `substring` in loops. What about [the longer `parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.CharSequence,int,int,int)) method or a regular expression using `Matcher.find()`?